# How to optimize MySQLl code that select for 300.000 rows +

Tags: php, mysql, bulk

I need to make XML files for a table that contains 300k+ records.

The code takes around 3~4s to finish (Is this acceptable?).

Add to that the data retrieval from MySQL, which takes around ~32s to finish (Is this acceptable?):

#### Query

```
SELECT `id`, `join_at` 
FROM girls g 
WHERE g.del_flg = 0 
ORDER BY g.join_at, g.id ASC
```

If I run this single query from the navicat mysql side it still takes around ~20s.

#### What I tried:

1. At first, the select query did not work because of a "memory exhausted" error (php.ini - memory_limit = 128M)
2. After that I changed `memory_limit` to -1. But I see that many people tell it's bad to change `memory_limit` into -1

So how to optimize the `select` query for 300k+ records in case of:

1. using PHP, sql, DOMDocument code only
2. Use options from #1 combined with an indexed column in the database
3. anything else that you know ...

#### PHP code with SQL query:

```
public function getInfo() {
    MySQL::connect();
    try {
        $select = 'SELECT `id`, `join_at`';
        $sql = ' FROM girls g';
        $sql .= ' WHERE g.del_flg = 0';
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY g.join_at, g.id ASC';
        $sql = sprintf($sql, $this->table);
        MySQL::$sth = MySQL::$pdo->prepare($select . $sql);
        MySQL::$sth->execute();
        while($rows = MySQL::$sth->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $values[] = array('id' => $rows['id'], 'join_at' => $rows['join_at']);
        }
        // $rows = MySQL::$sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        return null;
    }
    return $values;
}
```

I found out that `ORDER BY g.join_at, g.id ASC` part impacts the execution time. When I remove it, and use PHP instead for sorting, the execution time decreases from ~50s total to ~5s.

One more thing is that if I set `memory_limit` to 128M it leads to a "memory exhausted" error (512M will work). Is there any other solution for this problem?

Here are the indexes I currently have on the table:

[image: Index]

Comment: Don't do a `prepare()`. Just call  `query()` since you aren't binding anything here

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi: Depend, if `getInfo()` is called in a loop, prepare statement gives a better performance. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166798/mysql-pdo-prepared-faster-than-query-thats-what-this-simple-test-shows

Comment: @catcon Ah. I excuted getInfo() one time like this ```$Data= (new \App\Database\Girls\XML())->getInfo(); ```

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi Can you explain a bit more cuz I'm not good at sql though

Comment: @TùngTrầnDuy Please [edit] your question to include the result of the SQL query `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`. Also include the complete `CREATE TABLE` statement of your table to your question as well. Do you have any indices on your table? Can you add indices on the columns `del_flg` and maybe `join_at`?

Comment: @TùngTrầnDuy, that is not how this site works. Answers should be just that. Questions belong in the question section, not the answer section. It would be good if you would provide the information that Progman asked about in your question: it is relevant.

Comment: @Progman I'm afraid that I can not post those infomation here. So sorry :)

Comment: @TùngTrầnDuy, could you provide the definition of the indexes you have on the table.

Comment: @trincot yup I updated in question section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting is better done on the database side. But you need to define the proper indexes. The `order by` is expensive in your case. Although you have an index on `del_flg` which could prevent a table scan, it cannot be benefited from to produce the desired output order.

So I would suggest to alter the index `del_flg` you have to include more fields:

```
DROP INDEX del_flg ON girls;
CREATE INDEX del_flg ON girls (del_flg, join_at, id);
```

If that does not improve the execution time, then create an index that does not include `del_flag`:

```
CREATE INDEX join_at ON girls (join_at, id);
```